# PHP echo not working with session values even I got my session value

Tags: php

This is my core.php which disable direct access to the link

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';
    ob_start();

    if (!array_key_exists('uid', $_SESSION)) 
    {
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    else if($_SESSION['uid'] == "")
    {
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    else {}

?>
```

this is my header which will get the values from my login.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'B/core.php';
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
    $user_name = $_SESSION['fullname'];
    $user_pass = $_SESSION['upass'];
    $user_role = $_SESSION['utype'];
    $user_title = $_SESSION['utypetitle'];
    $user_uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $user_email = $_SESSION['uemail'];
?>
```

and this is my login script

```
if($value['pass'] === $lupass)
        {               
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['upass'] = $value['pass'];
        $_SESSION['utype'] = $value['acc_type'];
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $value['fname'];
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $value['lname'];
        $_SESSION['fullname'] = $value['fullname'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $value['id'];
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $value['uid'];
        $_SESSION['uemail'] = $value['email'];
```

And so my problem is when I echo the values in my div the php echo is not working and not retrieving any information in my database
`<?php echo $user_name;?>` what seems to be the problem? I fetch the value in the session and db but when I will echo it inside a div its not working

Comment: Did you check if `$_SESSION['fullname']` actually has a value (and its not an empty string)? Maybe you can just test with `print_r($_SESSION)`.

Comment: @RamRaider yes it has actually have a value and I tried everything but its not eorking I am using xampp btw

Comment: ob_start() will capture ALL output to STDOUT (echo) until you print it out.

Comment: @markuszeller can you ellaborate more?

Comment: remove ob_start() and troubleshoot, look at the error int he browser.

Comment: Will do ill follow up later

Comment: When you use ob_start() everything what will be outputted is captured until you tell to output it for example with echo ob_get_clean(). Why did you use ob_start() at all?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt remove the ob_start I just put the echo in a div thankyou so much guys